# Regression analysis on temperature/sensor data

Tags: regression, linear-approximation

Looking for a solution to what I thought should be an easy problem, but has me running in circles somehow...

I'm working with two sets of data: he first set is raw values from a sensor (accelerometer), and the second set is the temperatures at which these values were read. The values from the sensor are meaningless (as in, they're in sensor ticks) until run through the formula

$Value = (Ticks - OFFSET) * SCALE + Temp * CONST$

which gives me a $Value$ in useful units (in this case, $m/s^2$). The $OFFSET$ and $SCALE$ values are known; I'm trying to find a $CONST$ such that $Value = 0 m/s^2$ across all $Temp$.

The story here is that the sensor output changes over temperature even if its acceleration isn't changing due to the thermal characteristics of the sensor.

I had a similar problem with another sensor (granted, a different formula) and I was able to use simple linear regression to find the $CONST$, but for some reason it doesn't work for this data... One possible theory I've come up with is that the output being dependent on the temperature violates the independence requirement of linear regression, but if that is the case, what should I use instead to calculate a single $CONST$ that will result in the equation being zero (or near-zero) for all temperatures and tick values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that OFFSET is linear over temperature and that SCALE doesn't change with temperature.  If those assumptions were true, a linear regression would solve your problem.  You can make more complicated functions for OFFSET and SCALE-make each quadratic in temperature, for example.  Say your model is $OFFSET=A_0+A_1t+A_2t^2, SCALE=B_0+B_1t+B_2t^2$ (the $CONST$ will get absorbed in these) and feed your data to a multidimensional minimizer.  Programs are available in any numerical analysis text or in data analysis packages.

Comment: OFFSET and VALUE are actually both constant over all temperatures (or rather, I should say they are assumed to be). Only Ticks and Temp are variable, and Ticks is correlated with Temp (in that Ticks goes up when Temp does). Does this change the fact that I can still use linear regression?

Comment: But I can absorb the effect of CONST into a linear variation of OFFSET.  In essence, I am writing $Value=SCALE*(Ticks-OFFSET+Temp*CONST/SCALE).  My point is that if the fit doesn't work, this model is probably wrong, so you need a more complicated model to fit the data.  You could do what I said without the quadratic terms first and see how it does.

Comment: Ah, I follow you now. Unfortunately a more complicated model may be required (due to things beyond my control), but I will try your initial suggestion first, as it seems much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: This is already a somewhat more complicated model.  Whether it is enough to capture your data is to be seen.  Unfortunately, the more parameters you introduce, the higher the chance you fool yourself with one data set and it fails to work with the next one.

Comment: Duly noted - I'll try to see if I can come up with a simpler model in that case, since this will have to work for a large number of data sets.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Congrats on your 100k!

Answer (score 1):

You might fit this as a 3D model z = f(x,y) with temperature as one of the inputs.  The 3D Function Finder at http://zunzun.com can help find a surface equation to model the data, it is free online so the is no cost to try it.

The Python fitting source code is available at the Google Code Repository under an open source BSD license, it comes with many examples including parallel programming for maximum performance.

Source code link: http://code.google.com/p/pyeq2/

James